# Redis List Equivalent of SQL Where

Tags: redis

I am looking for a way to get a return of all keys of lists that contain a specific entry from a Redis DB.

In SQL it would be:

```
SELECT keys FROM db WHERE (3rd item in list) = 'foo';
```

Is this possible?